# Adding augmented reality to my app

Tags: android, android-studio, augmented-reality

I'm building an Android app in Android studios and decided to integrate augmented reality to my app.  Everything I found online uses vuforia and unity but don't explain how to use Android studio. Anywhere I should start specifically?

Also,  I just want to use a simple implementation of augmented reality,  have a character in one location based on gyroscope and location.  Kinda,  like Pokémon go.

Answer (score 0):

If you indeed choose Vuforia, they have an article for that: [Setting Up the Android Development Environment for Android Studio](https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Solution/Setting-Up-the-Android-Development-Environment-for-Android-Studio). Plus, they have working samples for Android Studio which you can download from their web site.